# Persistent Notification in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, xaml, notifications, winui-3, windows-11

I am currently working on a WinUI 3 program that will only be running on Windows 11 machines and I have implemented sending desktop notifications like such:

```cs
internal static bool SendNotification(string title, string message)
{
    try
    {
        AppNotification toast = new AppNotificationBuilder()
            .AddText(title)
            .AddText(message)
            .BuildNotification();

        AppNotificationManager.Default.Show(toast);
        return toast.Id != 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know after a couple of seconds, Windows will hide the notifications in the Notification Center, however, I want to make them stay on screen until the user either clicks on the notification or the little `x` to make them go away. Is there a way to do this in WinUI 3, or is it a Windows setting that can't be changed through my code?

Comment: Not sure you can do that programmatically (if ever at all), the whole idea with this new notification system is to not annoy the user with forced popups. She/He's basically in charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to specify the scenario for an app notification via [AppNotificationScenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.windows.appnotifications.builder.appnotificationscenario?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3)

In some scenarios, the notification will stay on screen until the user dismisses it or takes action. For example, Reminders or Incoming calls.

For more details, I suggest you refer to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=appsdk#scenarios).